# Show two topologies coincide on the unit ball.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, topological-vector-spaces, von-neumann-algebras

Consider the following lemma from "Lectures on von Neumann algebras":

[image]

I understand the proof of $(i)$ and $(ii)$. However, the proof says that $(iii)$ and $(iv)$ follow immediately from $(i)$ and $(ii)$. I can't see this. Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sigma(\mathscr E,\mathscr F)\subset \sigma(\mathscr E,\tilde{\mathscr F})$, the latter topology is stronger. Now suppose that $x_j\to x$ in $\sigma(\mathscr E,\mathscr F)$ and $x,x_j\in\mathscr E_1$ for all $j$. For any  $\varphi\in\tilde{\mathscr F}$, by $(ii)$, $\varphi$ is $\sigma(\mathscr E,\mathscr F)$-continuous, so $\varphi(x_j)\to\varphi(x)$. Thus $x_j\to x$ in $\sigma(\mathscr E,\bar{\mathscr F})$.

If $\mathscr F$ is closed and $\varphi$ is $\sigma(\mathscr E,\mathscr F)$-continuous on $\mathscr E_1$, by $(ii)$ you get that $\varphi\in\mathscr F$. By $(i)$, $\varphi$ is $\sigma(\mathscr E,\mathscr F)$-continuous.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to prove this with nets as well. However, I asked the question because it said 'the proof is immediate' and there still needed some work to be done.

Comment: I think you work too hard here: Assume $x_i \to 0$ on the unit ball for $\sigma(\mathscr{E}, \mathscr{F})$. Then for every $\psi \in \overline{\mathscr{F}}$, (ii) in the statement provided by the OP immediately implies that $\psi(x_i) \to 0$. Hence, since $\psi$ is arbitrary the convergence is also for the $\sigma(\mathscr{E}, \overline{\mathscr{F}})$-topology.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for noticing.